# YUI2 rich text editor, no var returned to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, yui

I am using Yahoo's YUI2 rich text editor that replaces a standard text area.  Without the RTE added the text area fields return the field contents correctly into my PHP code.  However when I use the RTE code the jQuery "sucks up" the var and doesn't give it back to the text area on submit.  Because of this the var (sectiontext1) is returning empty.  Here is the js for the text area:

```
var myEditor1 = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('sectiontext1', {
height: '100px',
    width: '870px',
    dompath: false,
    animate: true,
    toolbar: {
        titlebar: 'Section Text 1',
        buttons: [
            { group: 'textstyle', label: '',
                buttons: [
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Bold', value: 'bold' },
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Italic', value: 'italic' },
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Underline', value: 'underline' },
                    { type: 'separator' },
                    { type: 'color', label: 'Font Color', value: 'forecolor', disabled: true },
                    { type: 'separator' },
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Create an Unordered List', value: 'insertunorderedlist' },  
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Create an Ordered List', value: 'insertorderedlist' },                                  
                    { type: 'separator' },
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Indent', value: 'indent', disabled: true },
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Outdent', value: 'outdent', disabled: true },
                    { type: 'separator' },                  
                    { type: 'push', label: 'HTML Link CTRL + SHIFT + L', value: 'createlink', disabled: true }, 
                    { type: 'separator' },
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Remove Formatting', value: 'removeformat', disabled: true }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
myEditor1.render();
```

I thought I could just add this after the above and it would work but it doesn't:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
  myEditor1.saveHTML();
});
```

How do I get the code to return the var so I can use it in PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean doesn't work?
You may want to actually store the result in a variable and see if you got the html
If you do have the html in that var you can then use it any way you want, including sending it to php via ajax request.

```
var html = myEditor1.saveHTML();
alert('editor html: ' + html);
```

Comment: What I mean is that if I DO NOT use the rich text editor I get the variable's contents back in PHP.  If I use the rte, it somehow "holds" the var and it doesn't go back to the browser, so that var shows as empty.  I will try what you've listed here and see what happens.

Comment: Didn't work.  Something in that holds the variable.  i'm going to look at other optiosn like using TinyMCE

Comment: Oh no, please dont' give up. YUI RTE is so much better than TinyMCE. I've been using it for years, modified it, added new buttons, and it just always works.